# How to find data in multi-dimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say, I have something like below (quantities can be variable):

```
Product Color   XS   S    M    L    XL
   A    RED     100  200  200  200  100
   A    WHITE    50  100  200  100   20
   B    RED      50  200  200  100   50
   B    WHITE   100  200  300  200  100
```

If I saved them into array such as like this:

```
$product_array[] = 
    array('product' => 'A', 'color'  => 'RED',
          'XS'      => 100, 'S'      => 200,
          'M'       => 200, 'L'      => 200, 
          'XL' =>100);
```

What is the easiest way to find size quantity and update their given Product id and color? Let's say, (A, RED) sold XS size 10 qty?

Comment: I'd put it in a database.

Comment: Use the product name as the array index

Comment: Further than just the name as index - make each product name an index to a sub-array, and each product color a sub-array of that, which contains the sizes as keys. So `$products['A']['RED']['XL']` (really though, it would be simplest in a database)

Comment: all products and qty are read from database. now want to display to users given conditions

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments you could use item name + color as an index.
If you need to use given format you can create array of references to fasten things up.

```
$product_array[] = 
    array('product' => 'A', 'color'  => 'RED',
      'XS'      => 100, 'S'      => 200,
      'M'       => 200, 'L'      => 200, 
      'XL' =>100);
$product_array[] = 
    array('product' => 'B', 'color'  => 'GREEN',
      'XS'      => 100, 'S'      => 200,
      'M'       => 200, 'L'      => 200, 
      'XL' =>100);

foreach($product_array as &$product)
{
    $product_by_name_and_color[$product['product']][$product['color']] =& $product;
}
```

and then:

```
$product_by_name_and_color['B']['GREEN']['XS'] += 5;
print_r($product_array);
```

EDIT:

If your products are red from database, most probably you want to update values in database and you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: no, I do not want to update to db. once read from db. I need to perform totally different operation. I need to re-distribute them by given condition. back to your code, in foreach statement, how to match product and color after find it how to update qty for that matched item?

Comment: I guess this is what you meant                      foreach($product_array as &$p)
{
    
    if( $p['product'] == 'A' && $p['color'] == 'RED' )
    {
      $qty = $p['XS']+$p['S']+$p['M']+$p['L']+$p['XL'];
    }
   
}

Comment: foreach loop is just too create $product_by_name_and_color, an array of references. next bit of code shows how to update products.